# Interpreting high p value and low correlation value

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, computational-mathematics, correlation, regression-analysis

I am trying to run regression on financial data in R. I am new to regression analysis so I am finding it to difficult to interpret certain scenarios. I have the code as follows:

**Regression analysis**

> fit <- lm(fiveMinReturns~RegressionData, data=maindata)
>   summary(fit) # show results

**Correlation**

cor(maindata$fiveMinReturns,maindata$RegressionData,use="everything")

My output is:

> Call:
>   lm(formula = fiveMinReturns ~ RegressionData, data = maindata)
>
> Residuals:
>         Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
>   -0.205790 -0.001144 -0.000062  0.001117  0.156418
>
> Coefficients:
>                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
>   (Intercept)    6.346e-05  8.785e-06   7.223 5.09e-13 ***
>
> ### RegressionData 1.597e-07  1.432e-08  11.155  < 2e-16 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘***’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> Residual standard error: 0.004035 on 210912 degrees of freedom
>   Multiple R-squared:  0.0005896, Adjusted R-squared:  0.0005849 
>   F-statistic: 124.4 on 1 and 210912 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
>
> cor(maindata$fiveMinReturns,maindata$RegressionData,use="everything")
>   [1] 0.02428219

p-value is very small that means two variables are tightly coupled, but correlation is small too.

My question is how do I evaluate this situation? Can we say that this equation will give correct results almost every time?Which scenario suggests both p-value and correlation both to be really small?
What measures should i take to improve the result?

Answer (score 0):

A p-value does *not* mean the values are highly correlated, just that its highly unlikely to have arrived at your results, under your model, *assuming* they are not related. All you can conclude is that they are **not** *unrelated* (i.e., $\rho \neq 0$. The correlation gives an actual magnitude of the correlation, which in your case is small. There is no inconsistency here.

To improve your correlation, you'll need a better model. Also, neither correlation nor p-value speak to the *accuracy* or *precision* of your model's output. You'll need cross-validation to determine that.